# Running Ipython in cmd with colored background causes inconsistant background color

Tags: windows, cmd, ipython

When changing the cmd background and font color using the "color" function and running the IPython terminal the black background is used for some of the lines, most notably the entire prompt line. It looks like the default background in Ipython is black and it is used inconsistantly, sometimes as the background for the text displayed, sometimes as background for "padded" lines.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytRXg.png)

I have tried changing the color display to "NoColor" and "LightBG" using the %colors magic but that does not change the background color, just the font and I am lost where to begin looking for a solution. I would like IPython to consistantly use the background color that I set up as the cmd background.

Comment: is this a powershell window? That looks more like the terminal's color issues, though I've been struggling with it too.   I'm tending to use `NoColor` ipython option.

Comment: No, this is just windows' pure cmd with the option "color f0" with Ipython running. Sadly, NoColor affects only the font and the background does seem to still behave wildly. Tried just now whether it's going to behave the same if I run the powershell console and it looks like it has the same problem.

Comment: I was happy with `ipython` on a linux terminal, but not so much on windows.  `qtconsole` is another option.  That takes a `style` option.

Comment: I have found that choosing the "Use legacy console" options in the cmd properties make Ipython behave much better, I had no glitches with the background. Still would like to understand whether something could be done with the default console.

Comment: I like the lighter blue of the legacy screen, but I can run commands like `wsl` from there.  'nocolor' seems to be the best choice with the black terminal background.  I'm still struggling to make meaningful changes to the terminal's colores.